# AJAX response not showing correctly

Tags: php, ajax

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['Admin']) {
header('Location: login.php'); exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title> ticketExpress | Admin </title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../assets/css/style.css'> 
</head>
<body>
<div id='containerAdmin'>
<h1> <img class='logo' src='../assets/images/logo.png' width='200' height='43'> </h1> <a href='?logout' class='logout'> Logout </a>
<h3> Open Tickets </h3>
<hr />
<?php
require("../configuration/config.php");
$GetTickets = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE open='true'");
while($TicketInfo = $GetTickets->fetch_object()) {
$Subject = $TicketInfo->Subject;
echo "<div id='ticket'>".$Subject ."<a href='?delete=$TicketInfo->ID'><img style='float:right'src='../assets/images/delete.png' width='15px' height='15px'></a><a style='float:right; color:red; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;' href='?close=$TicketInfo->ID'> Close </a><font style='float:right; margin-right:10px;  color:green;' id='responseMsg". $TicketInfo->ID ."'> </font></div>";
if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {
$ID = $_GET['delete'];
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','delete.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('responseMsg".$TicketInfo->ID ."').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
        }
        ajax.send('delete=$ID');
    </script>
    ";
}
if(isset($_GET['close'])) {
$ID = $_GET['close'];
echo "
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','close.php', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('responseMsg".$TicketInfo->ID."').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        } 
        }
        ajax.send('close=$ID');
    </script>
    ";
}
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
<br />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The response text shows next to all tickets. How can I fix that? I only want it to show next to the ticket on which the "Delete" or "Close" button has been clicked. All answers are much appreciated. Thanks in advance

**delete.php**

```
<?php
require('../configuration/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$TID = $_POST['delete'];
$checkExist = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ID='$TID' AND open='true'");
$ch = $checkExist->num_rows;
if($ch >= 1) {
echo "Ticket Deleted";
$con->query("DELETE FROM tickets WHERE ID='$TID'");
}
}
```

**close.php**

```
<?php
require('../configuration/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['close'])) {
$TID = $_POST['close'];
$checkExist = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE ID='$TID' AND open='true'");
$ch = $checkExist->num_rows;
if($ch >= 1) {
echo "Ticket Closed";
$con->query("UPDATE tickets SET open='false' WHERE ID='$TID'");
}
}
```

Comment: :/ what is the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Unrelated to your original question, but you have easy to exploit sql injection problems. Escape your variables, or use prepared queries instead of using string interpolation. You can inject any query you want via `$_POST['close']`.

Answer (score 0):

in the code where you are echoing your div, you should write it as(in edited Question i just submitted)

```
 <div id="ticket<?php echo $TicketInfo->ID; ?>">
```

or if in your code you should do

```
 echo "<div id='ticket".$TicketInfo->ID."'>"
```

Also your **font** tag having **responseMsg id** is deprecated why don't you use a **div** instead, might solve your problem